# How to format the output of a TreeMap?

Tags: java, treemap

Currently, this is what I've tried:

```
System.out.println(treeMap.toString());
```

However, that prints the contents of the tree as:

```
{A=1, AND=1, BE=1, BY=2...}
```

How could I print the entire tree to be shown as below?

A=1

AND=1

BE=1

BY=2

Comment: can you show the full code?

Comment: You can do it one line with a lambda: `treeMap.entrySet().forEach(entry -> System.out.println(String.format("%s=%d\n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())));`

Comment: @Jameson `.forEach` directly on the TreeMap also works: `treeMap.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k + " " + v));`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
treeMap.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k + "=" + v + "\n"));
```

Comment: @RobinTopper what's the issue?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Your answer could be shorter. And yes, Jameson, it was pointed out to me earlier that a comment is not an answer ...

Comment: @Jameson why would you include "\n"?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw OP has empty lines between each desired output

Comment: I doubt the extra lines are required. OP probably didn't know how to format a newline.

Comment: @shmosel yeah that's what I thought as well. I guess ill just show both ways and specify the reasons being.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put("A", 1);
map.put("B", 2);
map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```